# ~/.pam_environment doesn't work since Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, environment-variables, pam-environment

I have this line in my `~/.pam_environment`:

```
PATH             DEFAULT=${HOME}/bin:${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}
```

and it worked perfectly well on Ubuntu 12.10, but since I've updated to 13.04 it is completely ignored:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Also see: [PATH is not affected by .pam_environment](http://askubuntu.com/q/304976/59378).

Answer (score 0):

`~/.pam_environment` does not use the normal syntax and you should strictly follow the [pam_env.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_env.conf) syntax.

> **Note:** Using `.pam_environment` requires a **re-login** in order to initialize the variables. Restarting just the terminal is not sufficient to be able to use the variables.

Source: [Session-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables).

But I think that the right place to define environment variables such as PATH is `~/.profile` or `~/bashrc` file (if you put them here you don't need to re-login).

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to re-login, I did that multiple times (even rebooteed) but there there was absolutely no change... It worked in Ubuntu 12.10, why would it stop doing that?

Comment: Can you please tell me what's wrong with my syntax as I can't see anything wrong?

Comment: @szx What permission have you on this file? The result of `ls -l .pam_environment`?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--` |||||||||||

Comment: In my case it works by just having the assignement (not the pam_env syntax) in the files, like VAR=value. Maybe you have an encripted home dir? Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/584249 and related bugs...

Comment: By the way, `.pam_environment` is better than `.profile` if you, like me, use a different shell like zsh.