# PATH is not affected by .pam_environment

Tags: 13.04, environment-variables, pam-environment

Running Ubuntu 13.04, I'm trying to add variables to `PATH` for the session, which is [recommended to do inside `.pam_environment`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), but nothing seems to work. Here's what it looks like:

```
JAVA_HOME          DEFAULT=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
IDEA_HOME          DEFAULT=/usr/local/idea-IU-129.451/bin
LIGHTTABLE_HOME    DEFAULT=/usr/local/LightTable
CLOUDIFY_HOME      DEFAULT=/home/eliranm/builds/gigaspaces-cloudify
PATH               DEFAULT=${PATH}    OVERRIDE=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}:${IDEA_HOME}:${LIGHTTABLE_HOME}:${CLOUDIFY_HOME}
```

It seems all variables are set but the `PATH`, or that it is overridden somehow. I tried to prepend or append the `${PATH}` variable, to use `DEFAULT` only, `OVERRIDE` only, tried to just set a hard-coded path as a value, all to no avail.

I'm following the recommendations from the Ubuntu help community, and I want to avoid concatenating hard-coded paths to the `PATH` inside `/etc/environment` as it's not the right scope, plus, it will be hard to maintain with no variables.

Others may be affected by this issue, [as stated here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301914/pam-environment-doesnt-work-since-ubuntu-13-04), but no one provided a solution so far.

How to make this work?

Comment: Using `.pam_environment` requires a **re-login** in order to initialize the variables.

Comment: i'm aware of that, neither **re-login** nor **reboot** works..

Comment: Ok, good to know. And the result of `ls -l .pam_environment`?

Comment: `ls -l .pam_environment` outputs `-rw-r--r-- 1 eliranm eliranm 426 Jun  6 23:04 .pam_environment`, but permissions has nothing to do with the issue at hand - the file is being executed and all variables short the `PATH` are being assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using `$PATH` variable inside the scope of `/etc/environment` or `~/.pam_environment` does not get resolved, but assigned just as is literally.

In fact I see using `$PATH` or any variable inside `~/.pam_environment` being discouraged on most post I read like here: [Why doesn't my environment variable get set](https://superuser.com/questions/130135/why-doesnt-my-environment-variable-get-set).

So I don't really know why here ([Session-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables)) they tell to use `$PATH` in it.

I know that Debian removed the parsing of the local `~/.pam_environment` as it is a high security risk.

Anyway for my understanding the two files `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment` use a simpler syntax (simple `KEY=VAL` pairs for each line) then `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` (`VARIABLE [DEFAULT=[value]] [OVERRIDE=[value]]`). So perhaps no reference to variable can be made at all inside them.

Comment: well, we should fix the docs on ubuntu help, than. at least for 13.04 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

I have been running into this as well because I was trying to do it the way documentation said (I traditionally use Redhat based systems).

I think using ${PATH} only works if your path was originally set in the /etc/security/pam_env.conf file.  It appears to me that the original path is set in /etc/login.defs, and then isn't available.

I dropped back to setting the values in ~/.profile, I have spent too much time debugging this seemingly simple thing. It makes me wonder what other Ubuntu users do, we can't be the first ones who wanted to append to the path variable.  I'm guessing they have done the same, and ignored ~/.pam_environment.

Comment: For those coming later, this is still an issue and .profile is nothing to do with it when using gnome on wayland. Wayland does not use .profile.