# How do I configure terminal using .profile?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to change some configuration of terminal, but I did not find `MAIL`, `PATH`, `PS1`, and `PS2` in `.profile`.

Please tell me where will I find these, and what I have to do if I want to change `PS1`, `PS2` and `PATH` using the `.profile` file?

Answer (score 0):

`PS1` is defined under `.bashrc`. If you look in the file, you'll find this section:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

By default, you should edit the first `PS1` line to change your prompt's color.

You can add a `PS2` at the end of this file, because by default, it's not there.

---

To add directories to your `PATH`, you should add the below to the end of the file `~/.pam_environment`:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/MyPrograms
```

- Where `${HOME}/MyPrograms` is the path that you want to append to your `PATH` variable.

This is the new, recommended way (as per [Ubuntu Help: Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables)).

The old way was to add the below to `.profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory
```

- Where `/path/to/directory` is the path that you want to append to your `PATH` variable.
- **Note**: more information about this "new" and "old" way here: [PATH is not affected by .pam_environment](https://askubuntu.com/q/304976/52726)

---

I am unfamiliar with `MAIL`, but from my brief search, it seems like it's just another variable. You can add the below line to `.profile` as well:

```
export MAIL=/path/to/whatever/this/is
```

- Where `/path/to/whatever/this/is` is the path you want to set in the variable.

Answer (score -1):

I usually set those in .bashrc, but I use bash.